# Player disappears when it collides with a tagged object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting, collision

I am working on a simple game where the goal is to help a Player catch specific objects with a tag "Present".

After taking care of the models, animations I am now working on the collisions and counting UI.

For the collisions, on my Player Controller (I am using the ThirdPersonUserController from the player [Unity Standard Assets](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/essentials/asset-packs/standard-assets-for-unity-2017-3-32351) - which simplified the whole animation process), I added the following functions:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.tag == "Present")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        count = count - 1;
        SetCountText();
    }
}

void SetCountText()
{
    countText.text = "Count: " + count.ToString();
    if (count == 0)
    {
        winText.text = "Thanks to you the Christmas will be memorable!";
    }
}
```

However, like this, when the Player hits an object with the tag "Present", even though the counting is working properly, the player disappears.

I have tried to change the `OnCollisionEnter` to an `OnTriggerEnter`, like this:

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Present"))
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        count = count - 1;
        SetCountText();
    }
}
```

However when the Player hits the objects with the tag "Present", they don't disappear.

My Player has a Capsule Collider and a Rigidbody.

The objects with the tag "Present" have a Box Collider and a Rigidbody.

Any guidance on how to make my Player stay in scene while removing the other objetcs and reducing the count is appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to make the player disappear with `Destroy(gameObject);`?

Comment: I am trying to make the object, with the tag "Present" disappear when the player collides with it.

Comment: `Destroy(gameObject);` has nothing to do with the present `GameObject`. Maybe you mean to use `Destroy(other.gameObject);`? Also, if your collider is not set to be a trigger, you should be using `OnCollisionEnter`, not `OnTriggerEnter`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your present object is using a non-trigger collider, so you should use `OnCollisionEnter`. The `CompareTag` call you tried in `OnTriggerEnter` is preferable. You should use that.

Also, you are currently trying to destroy the gameobject that the `ThirdPersonUserController` is attached to (`gameObject`). Instead, destroy the gameobject of the colliding collider (`other.gameObject`) with `Destroy(other.gameObject);`:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
{
    if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Present"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
        count = count - 1;
        SetCountText();
    }
}
```

Comment: Consider upvoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59185385/7109869) as well, as it has an extra consideration related with performance.

Answer (score 5):

Few things. You are destroying the incorrect game object:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.tag == "Present")
        {
            Destroy(gameObject); // this is destroying the current gameobject i.e. the player
            count = count - 1;
            SetCountText();
        }
    }
```

Update to:

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("Present"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject); // this is destroying the other gameobject
            count = count - 1;
            SetCountText();
        }
    }
```

Always use `CompareTag()` which is optimized for performance.

Setting the Collider `IsTrigger` property will then make use of the `OnTriggerEnter` events and not the `OnCollisionEnter` anymore.

> On the first physics update where the collision is detected, the
> OnCollisionEnter function is called. During updates where contact is
> maintained, OnCollisionStay is called and finally, OnCollisionExit
> indicates that contact has been broken. Trigger colliders call the
> analogous OnTriggerEnter, OnTriggerStay and OnTriggerExit functions.

See the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html)

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer.
As Ruzihm helped me solve the problem in the comment section, I approved his answer, even though your answer has extra considerations that may be useful.